# Excel - Return all column headers if columns do not contain TRUE

Tags: excel

I want to return all columns headers of hundreds of columns in which "TRUE" is not under - meaning ones that only have "FALSE" values. Could someone help recommend an easy way of doing this? I've tried various methods but found that they are still very manual.

[image]

I am unfamiliar with VBA - just tried to use Pivots and some VLOOKUP and HLOOKUPS and haven't come near the solution I want.

Comment: Any one occurrence of false in a column? Can you add rows or columns? Where do you want to "return" the results?

Comment: @NetMage Only columns in which FALSE is under, no instance of TRUE. Yes, I can add freely add rows and columns, sorry I did not specify this.

Comment: *I've tried various methods but found that they are still very manual.* - Show us methods you've tried and where they are not working. It will be manual (some methods faster than others) unless you use vba. To do that you need to know or learn the language then write the code.

Comment: Specifically extending NetMage's question above, are you after an in-cell formula or a macro?

Comment: @neophlegm An in-cell formula would be ideal, if that's possible in a clean way.

Comment: How do you want the answer to be presented? A single cell with headers separated by commas, a row of cells with each header in one cell, a column of cells with each header in one cell?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.

**1)** Insert a row above your data. You can hide later if you want. Or you can write this formula across the corresponding columns in another tab (see step 5).

**2)** cell A1 formula = `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(TRUE,A3:A5000,0)),1,0)`

**3)** cell B1 formula = `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(TRUE,B3:B5000,0)),MAX($A$1:A1)+1,0)`.

**4)** drag over for as many columns as needed and adjust `5000` row count as needed

[image]

**5)** On another tab in A1 write the formula: `=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(ROW(),data!$1:$2,2,0),"")` where data is the sheet with data.

**6)** drag down for as many rows as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the headers that match in a single row, and assuming you want one matching header per cell:

1. Add three rows above the existing header row.
2. In cell `A3`, put the formula

   `=AND(A5:A####)`

   and copy it across all the columns used. (Replace #### with the last row #.)
3. In cell `A2`, put the array formula

   `=INDEX($A$4:$E$4,SMALL(IF($A$3:$E$3,COLUMN($A$3:$E$3)),COLUMN(A:A)))`

   (Type it in, press Ctrl-Shift-Enter.)
   Replace `E` with the last column used.
   Copy it across all columns used.
4. In cell `A1`, put the formula

   `=IFERROR(A2,"")`

   and copy it across all columns used.

You should see all the valid headers in row 1 followed by blank cells.

I broke the formula in two rows (1, 2) so you wouldn't have to repeat the `INDEX` expression twice in the `IF`, but you could combine them.

Here is an alternative that doesn't need array formulas:

1. Add three rows above the existing header row.
2. In cell `A3`, put the formula

   `=IF(AND(A5:A####),1)`

   Replace #### with the last row #.
3. In cell `B3`, put in the formula

   `=IF(AND(B5:B####),COUNTIF($A$3:A3,"<>FALSE")+1)`

   Replace #### with the last row #. Copy it across to all remaining used columns.
4. In cell `A2`, put the formula

   `=HLOOKUP(COLUMN(A:A),$A$3:$E$4,2,FALSE)`

   Copy it across to all used columns.
5. In cell `A1`, put the formula

   `=IFNA(A2,"")`

   and copy it across to all used columns.